# XML format specification (DTD, XSD..) for Unit Test Reports

Tags: xml, unit-testing, xsd, report, dtd

A lot of tools produces and consumes the same XML File format for Unit Test report.

Example ([source](http://junitpdfreport.cvs.sourceforge.net/junitpdfreport/src/resources/examples/testresults/)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" hostname="hazelnut.osuosl.org" name="net.cars.engine.MoteurTest" tests="6" time="0.021" timestamp="2007-11-02T23:13:50">
  <properties>
    <property name="java.vendor" value="IBM Corporation" />
    <property name="os.name" value="Linux" />
    <!-- more property tags-->
  </properties>
  <testcase classname="net.cars.engine.MoteurTest" name="hasBougie" time="0.0010" />
  <testcase classname="net.cars.engine.MoteurTest" name="hasCarburatueur" time="0.0010" />
  <!-- more testcase tags-->
  <system-out><![CDATA[]]></system-out>
  <system-err><![CDATA[]]></system-err>
</testsuite>
```

After a little bit research, I have found that the format was proposed by the apache foundation (by the ant project).

Produced by:

- junit ant task
- antunit
- maven surefire
- testng
- ...

Consumed by:

- junitreport ant task
- maven surefire-reports
- CruiseControl
- Luntbuild
- Bamboo
- Hudson/Jenkins
- IntelliJ TeamCity
- AntHill
- Parabuild
- JUnit PDF Report
- ...

The only document I could find is this page on the ant wiki: 
[Proposals/EnhancedTestReports](http://wiki.apache.org/ant/Proposals/EnhancedTestReports)

Is there any specification of this format (DTD, XSD) ?

I want to write a such file from hand... (or maybe use a librairy if you know any)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This page http://windyroad.org/2011/02/07/apache-ant-junit-xml-schema/ suggests that the XML Schema for JUnit test reports is here http://windyroad.org/dl/Open%20Source/JUnit.xsd

The structure of that schema seems to match the example you have given.

Answer (score 0):

Schema can be found in [maven surefire documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/xsd/surefire-test-report.xsd) or in the [source repository](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/maven-surefire-plugin/src/site/resources/xsd/surefire-test-report.xsd)