# export test report (format xml)

Tags: xml, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800,800))
display.start() 
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/andrey/Downloads/chromedriver')
browser.get('http://www.google.com/')

try:
   browser.find_element_by_id('gbw')
   print ("Test Pass: ID found")
   browser.find_element_by_id('lga')
   print ("Test Pass: ID found")

except Exception as e:
   print("Exception found",format(e))
   raise Exception('jenkins')
```

I want to export test report for this test (format xml). I try to use Xunit but I can't find some example, how I can export test report with Xunit. [Xunit](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/xunit.htm)

Comment: The link your provided was bad. Have you read the docs here: http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html#nose.plugins.xunit.Xunit?

Comment: Yes and I don't fined any information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create report for Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750677/how-to-create-report-for-jenkins)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post the same question again. Instead, you can edit your previous question with additional information, see [What to do if no one answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: In the context of Jenkins, XUnit is not really an output format, but a plugin that can understand XML test report formats from a number of tools. There are several related questions that describe the JUnit XML format: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4922867/172599, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8079071/172599